# Match comma seperated list with input in SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Im optimizing my SQL statement to make it faster.

I have a comma seperated list with zipcodes like

1111, 1112,1115,1112 etc etc

Now in my query I want to match if the iput matches 1 of those zipcodes. If so.. then it will return a ID of the object that has all those zipcodes.

But what is the best way to do this now im doing

```
AND ( loc.loc_zip LIKE  '%".$_REQUEST['zip']."%'
```

Validation of the input will be added ofcourse.. but this is just for testing. But I have tested this and it seems a bit slow.

Is this the best way to do this ?

Comment: It will return an ID of the object that has all those zipcodes?  Don't you mean any of those zip codes?  Also, if loc.loc_zip contains more than zip code per record, the best way to do this is to re-design your database so that there is a one to many relationship between whatever your app is about and zip codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use 'in'

```
select * from Users where userid in (1,2,3,4,45,6,656)
```

Edit:
if the ZipCodes are Chars, you can only use in if you separate them by ''

```
select * from loc where loc.loc_zip in ('1111','1112','1115','1112')
```

if .$_REQUEST['zip']. has ' ' then->

```
select * from loc where loc.loc_zip in (.$_REQUEST['zip'].)
```

if the ZipCodes are int you can use the first statement
Bare in mid you must intersect your list with '' or it wont work

Comment: so in my case something like where $_REQUEST['zip'] IN loc.loc_zip ??

Comment: My vote put your reputation into 3 digits.  You owe me a beer.

Comment: whhy is this better then LIKE btw?

Comment: beacuse in a list you cant use LIKE, like is for a single entry, IN is for lists